# replace "for loops" with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by

I am trying to calculate total track time by each player in a trial. Each row in the data frame has columns `['trial','time','player','event']`. The `'event'` column reports whether the track has been initiated, updated, or dropped. I can do the calculation with for loops but I want to optimize run time. I can't figure out how to use groupby with strings and conditions.

This code works in calculating the total track time for each player but I have 50 trials and hundreds of rows per trial. The run time is slow using for loops.
I would like to remove as many for loops as possible. I looked into groupby but I don't know how to incorporate the conditions for each event with groupby.
Not all players will have a track drop when the trial ends.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'trial':[101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102,102,102],
                   'time':[3,3,4,4,5,5,8,9,10,5,6,7,8,8,9],
                   'player':['tx-1','tx-2','tx-1','tx-2','tx-1','tx-2','tx-2','tx-2','tx-2','tx-1','tx-1','tx-1','tx-1','tx-3','tx-1'],
                   'event':['track initiated','track initiated','track update','track update','track drop','track drop',
'track initiated','track update','track drop','track initiated','track update','track update',
'track update','track initiated','track update']})

trials = set(df.trial)
track_results = []
for t in trials:
    trial_data = df[df['trial'] == t]
    unique_plrs = set(trial_data['player'])
    for plr in unique_plrs:
        plr_df = trial_data[trial_data['player'] == plr]
        plr_df.reset_index(inplace = True)
        total_track_time = 0
        for idx, row in plr_df.iterrows():
            time = row['time']
            event = row['event']
            if idx == 0:
                track_segment = 0
                prev_time = time
            elif 'initiated' in event:
                track_segment = 0
            elif 'update' in event:
                track_segment = time - prev_time
            elif 'drop' in event:
                track_segment = time - prev_time
            prev_time = time                     
            total_track_time += track_segment
        track_results.append([t,plr,total_track_time])  
track_results = pd.DataFrame(track_results,columns = ['trial','player','total track time'])
```

[Here is the sample data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFC3Y.png)

Comment: are we supposed to type out that sample data ourselves?

Comment: I changed my question to include the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
 import pandas as pd

# Creating a DataFrame with below json data
data = {
    'trial': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'time': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 1.1, 1.5],
    'player': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'event': ['initiated', 'update', 'initiated',
              'update', 'drop', 'update', 'update', 'update', 'update', 'update']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

''' Calculate the time difference between consecutive rows within each trial 
    and player group
'''
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(['trial', 'player'])['time'].diff()

# Identify the rows where a new trial or player starts
new_trial_player_mask = (
                        df['trial'] != df['trial'].shift()) | 
                        (df['player'] != df['player'].shift()
                        )

# Set the time difference to 0 for the first row of each trial or player group
df.loc[new_trial_player_mask, 'time_diff'] = 0

# Calculate the total track time for each player in each trial
df['total_track_time'] = df.groupby(['trial', 'player'])['time_diff'].cumsum()

# Keep only the last row for each trial and player combination
track_results = df[new_trial_player_mask].reset_index(drop=True)
                  [['trial', 'player', 'total_track_time']]

# Display the output
print(track_results)
```

The whole code can be reduced removing all the for loops. Hopefully this helps what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
` track_results = df[new_trial_player_mask].reset_index(drop=True)
                  [['trial', 'player', 'total_track_time']] `    
give me the first row for each trial and player combination.